# Batch to read text files and replace quotes with variables into new file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have customer pizza lists that I have saved into 5 separate .txt files from my database in this format:

```
Filename = 25Percent.TXT
"555-1211"
"555-1212"
"555-1223"
```

Each list is a phone number in quotes and each list varies in length.

**First question**
I have two sets of variables that I would like to replace with each quote in the 5 text files.
The two variables would be like:

```
Var A = < Discount Pizza price for phone number is "
Var B = " 25 % >
```

I would like to run a batch file that reads each line in the text file and writes into another text file the following, replacing the quotes with the variables:

```
New Filename = 25Percentfinished.TXT
< Discount Pizza price for phone number is "555-1211" 25 % >
< Discount Pizza price for phone number is "555-1212" 25 % >
< Discount Pizza price for phone number is "555-1223" 25 % >
```

Then I would repeat for *30percent.txt*, *35percent.txt*, *40percent.txt* and finally *50percent.txt* file.

**Second Question**
I would also like to append the 5 new files together

Comment: If you've got Excel, this is going to be a lot easier to do in there.

Comment: It is generally not recommended to ask two questions at once. Each question should be asked separately.

Comment: appending files together is simply `copy file1+file2+file3+...+fileN bigfile`

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple `for` loop:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (25Percent.txt) do (
    echo ^< Discount Pizza price for phone number is %%a 25 %%% ^>>>25Percentfinished.txt
)
```

See `for /?` for usage. This processes the file line by line, reading the line into the variable `%%a` and appending the modified line to the other file. The `<` and `>` are escaped with `^` (making `^<` and `^>`) because they have a special meaning in the command prompt. The `%` is 'escaped' with `%%%` because it's also a special character, but cannot be escaped like the others.

---

You can combine multiple text files like so:

```
copy file1.txt + file2.txt + file3.txt destination.txt
```

Or you can loop with `type` and append (`>>`) (this will combine all files in the current directory, in alphabetical ascending sorted order):

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    type %%a>>destination.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the OS so I'll provide a solution that'll work if you have `sed` available.

```
$ sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/< Discount Pizza price for phone number is \1 25 % >/' < 25Percent.TXT
```

Comment: The OS is specified although indirectly. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file